# Using a laptop to communicate with an MBED module

Tags: communication, rs232, mbed

I'm using an external power source to power an MBED module. I have the UART transfer and receive ports connected to a MAX232 level switcher in order to make the signals compatible with RS232. From there the wires go to an RJ-45 connector, which goes to a DB9 connector that is connected to a USB-DB9 converter. This is connected to the laptop.

With this setup, I should be able to program the CPU to write text which will appear in a terminal program like HyperTerminal in Windows, correct? I've tried several things, but haven't been able to get any input in HyperTerminal. What's a simple program I can use to test my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the mbed module - [check this page out](http://mbed.org/handbook/Serial)

the easiest code for it to test would be

> include "mbed.h" 
> Serial device(p9, p10);  // tx, rx
> int main() {
> device.baud(19200);
> device.printf("Hello World\n");
> }

Hope this helps

Comment: another page that may help http://mbed.org/handbook/SerialPC